# Ubuntu 19.10 is locking screen suddenly

Tags: lock-screen

I have an ubuntu 19.10, but from Thursday the **screen is locking randomly while I am working**, ubuntu ask to me my password and the screen unlocks, but I have **every program close**.
I have thought that the pc go on protection, but the pc sometimes is cold.

I think that the problem was appear after an update

thanks for the reply

Comment: You're crashing. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`, and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and `free -h`, and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: thank you

ls -al /var/crash command return 

drwxrwsrwt  2 root  whoopsie    4096 mag  5 18:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root        4096 apr 16  2019 ..
-rw-r-----  1 david whoopsie 7623686 mag  5 18:53 _usr_lib_tracker_tracker-miner,

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/david/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': File o directory non esistente

I have tried also with sudo but returns the same

Comment: ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

totale 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 nov 25 17:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 nov 23 11:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 nov 23 11:27 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mar 15 18:45 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Comment: free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       3,9Gi       147Mi       265Mi       3,6Gi       3,3Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi        63Mi       1,9Gi

Comment: systctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for the info. As you can see, placing that much data into comments makes it very difficult to read. Best to edit your question and then paste in the text there. Anyway, I only see one crash log in /var/crash... have you been manually deleting files there? How often has this problem occurred? Also, did you delete the Desktop Icons Gnome Shell extension? It's missing too.

Comment: Show me the output of `grep -i stack -A5 /var/log/syslog*`. If that's a lot of output, paste it in at paste.ubuntu.com.